# Making a logging.Handler with async emit

Tags: python, logging, python-asyncio

I have a Python log handler that writes using asyncio (it's too much work to write to this particular service any other way). I also want to be able to log messages from background threads, since a few bits of code do that. So my code looks basically like this (minimal version):

```
class AsyncEmitLogHandler(logging.Handler):
    def __init__(self):
        self.loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
        super().__init__()

    def emit(self, record):
        self.format(record)
        asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(
            coro=self._async_emit(record.message),
            loop=self.loop,
        )

    async def _async_emit(message):
        await my_async_write_function(message)
```

Mostly it works fine but when processes exit I get a lot some warnings like this: "coroutine 'AsyncEmitLogHandler._async_emit' was never awaited"

Any suggestions on a cleaner way to do this? Or some way to catch shutdown and kill pending writes? Or just suppress the warnings?

Note: the full code is [here][1]
[1]: https://github.com/lsst-ts/ts_salobj/blob/c0c6473f7ff7c71bd3c84e8e95b4ad7c28e67721/python/lsst/ts/salobj/sal_log_handler.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this solution which will block closing until everything have finished emitting?

I'm using this where I use the QueueHandler and QueueListener as well to have the logging happen in a separate thread (this is also why I create a new event loop)

```py
class AsyncEmitLogHandler(logging.Handler):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.loop = asyncio.new_event_loop() 

    def emit(self, record):
        self.format(record)
        self.loop.create_task(self._async_emit(record.message))

    async def _async_emit(message):
        await my_async_write_function(message)

    def close(self) -> None:
        self.loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*asyncio.all_tasks(self.loop)))
        self.loop.close()
```

Comment: I am no longer working on the codebase in question, but will assume this does the job.

Answer (score 0):

You could keep a reference to the coro, and override the handler's `close()` method to call `close()` on it. A general way to manage coros is to keep a list of them in the handler, and override the handler's `close()` method to call `close()` on each coro, or else create tasks from them and call `cancel()` on each of the tasks.

Comment: Good suggestion. I'll try that. In fact asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe returns a concurrent.futures.Future which I could use to keep track of things -- purge them as they are done (when emit is called) and then close the remaining ones at the end.

Comment: I tried saving the futures returned from run_coroutine_threadsafe and cancelling them in an override of the close method, but I still see the warnings about coros not awaited. I added a print statement to make sure the close was called and had futures to cancel. Any ideas?

Comment: I tried using asyncio.create_task when I could (when run from the main thread) and most of the warnings went away. So somehow asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe is causing the warnings (even if I cancel the unfinished ones in close). I don't understand it. So...better but not fully fixed.